# Conservar valores en ViewBag/ViewData al navegar otra vista MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Resulta que tengo una pagina el cual tiene un navbar, este navbar lo agrege al `_layout` como `PartialView`

**CONTROLADOR**

```
 [ChildActionOnly]
        public PartialViewResult BarraNavegacion()
        {
            if (Session["cambio"] == null)
            {
                string fechaActual = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                string xml = indicadorEconocomico.ObtenerIndicadoresEconomicosXML("318", fechaActual, fechaActual, "xxx", "S");
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.LoadXml(xml);
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
                Session["cambio"] = json;
                ViewBag.dolar = Session["cambio"].ToString();
            }


            return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_navbar.cshtml");
        }
```

Estoy guardando lo que quiero mostrar en un `ViewBag`, de aqui al mostrar la parte del `navbar` me muestra el `ViewBag`

**NAVBAR**

```
<li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
    <h5 class="cambioHoy">Tipo de cambio: @ViewBag.dolar</h5>
</li>
```

Cuando corro la pagina web, me muestra el valor del dolar, cuando navego a otra vista, la informacion se pierde (osea no se muestra nada), como puedo mostrar la info del navbar en todas vistas? (tomando en cuenta que es `navbar` es un `PartialView`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu caso veo que el "tipo de cambio" lo estás almacenando el la sesión `Session["cambio"] = json;`.

Entonces no te haría falta utilizar el `ViewBag` para acceder al "tipo de cambio" en la Vista que tu quieras. Simplemente utiliza el valor que tienes almacenado en la sesión directamente el la Vista.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
<li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
<h5 class="cambioHoy">Tipo de cambio: @Session["cambio"]</h5>
```